# Side length of regular decagon

Tags: polygons

Ok, so here are the informations.

Area: $770 \;\mathrm{cm}^2$

bottom to top: $30.8$

height: half of $30.8$ = $15.4$

Find the perimeter?

Comment: What kind of decagon? Regular?

Comment: Sorry, yes regular. How do you exactly know the side length is my question also.

Comment: The perimeter is $10s$ where $s$ is the side length. Connect the centre to two adjacent vertices. You can (trig) express the area of the triangle in terms of $s$.

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite understand.

Comment: The question has already been answered elsewhere. Odd question, since if we know the height we can compute the area, and vice-versa.

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_regular_polygon.htm